# Database table contains combinations of data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm working on a client's website, he uses MySQL for the database, I just want to confirm there's something wrong with his database design. The purpose of his site is so client's can receive a 'certificate'. A certificate can be issued for a combination of a program and scope. So when his applicant's apply for a certificate, that certification is for a particular program and scope combination.

He has a table called 'scopes' It may as well be called 'program_scope_combos' Inside it is all the program and scope combos, it looks something like this:

```
id - program_name - scope_name
1  - DEF          - crops
2  - DEF          - livestock
3  - ABC          - crops
4  - ABC          - plants
5  - XYZ          - plants
```

Can somebody point out if this **is violating rules to having a normalized database?**

On top of this there is a table that lists only the programs but that looks normal.

```
'programs' table
id - name - abbreviation
```

What I have suggested to him is the following:

```
 'applications' table
 id - client_id - program_id - scope_id - created_at

 'certificates' table
 id - name - application_id - status - created_at

 'programs' table
 id - name - abbreviation

 'scopes' table
 id - name - abbreviation
```

Some notes on this database. There's also a clients table. A client can have many applications. Thanks so much.

Comment: The `scopes` table is not properly normalized, no. The program_name and scope_name are duplicated, which would mean an update to the program's or scopes name would mean you'd have to directly update the `scopes` table, rather than a parent table. However, that does not mean it is wrong, or invalid to have this type of schema.

Comment: `id` (in the first table) appears to have no purpose in this design. A natural key exists on (program_name,scope_name). However, given that both programs and scopes have surrogate PK ids, it's these that should be referenced in the linking table.